# Using WPF on XP embedded for simple GUI

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-xp, kiosk, windows-xp-embedded

I've got a simple and clean GUI to do for windows XP embedded, but I'm very new to C#.

Many topics I've found discussing WPF on XPE seem to be dating back to ~2007, so I'm here hoping for current up-to-date information.

Basically, how well supported would WPF be for this task? Are there circumstances which makes this a very bad design path? (what .net version?)

The app will be a kiosk mode gui which will contain some simple buttons, textfields and maybe a drawing canvas element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should at least be possible for you to get .Net Framework 3.0 installed on XPe (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb417255%28WinEmbedded.5%29.aspx). However, depending on the performance you've got available and the kind of UI (if its simple enough), you might opt to choose WinForms instead of WPF.